# how to add attribute to each list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, sorting, height

i have a string which looks like this:

```
.a,.b,.c,.d
```

i would like to add a value to an attribute of every one of these
items.

i used this before to add a value to items where i change the height:

```
$(this).attr("heightwert", parseInt($(this).css('height')));
```

i use this attribute for sorting.
but if you know how i could sort by the dynamical height of elements this would be great too.

this i use for sorting:

```
onclick="$('ul.dataa&gt;li').tsort('a',{attr:'heightwert',order:'desc'});"
```

Comment: What's your actual mark-up? Can you post a live-[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) so's we can see what you're working with?

Comment: Is that .a,.b,.c,.d a string or a collection of objects?

Comment: thats a string im getting from an attribute of an element.. is it something with $each i could use? i just cant find how...

Comment: How does the string relate to the page? Are there elements of those classes on the page that you're trying to affect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was written with the assumption that the `.a,.b,.c,.d` was a reference to the class-names of elements on the page, though reading the comments that follow my posting this answer I'm not sure that this is, indeed, the case. However, on my original assumption, the following seems to do what (I thought) you asked:

```
$('.a, .b, .c, .d').attr('data-heightwert', function(i, val) {
    return $(this).height();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2tSBA/).

Please note that I'm using the attribute `data-heightwert` rather than simply `heightwert` as that would be an invalid attribute of an html element, whereas the `data-` prefix allows for elements to be assigned/created as necessary by the developer and retain validity of the code. Admittedly this is under html 5, but it's backwards compatible with html 4.x, and is, at worst, no less valid than simply using `heightwert` in such doctypes.

The heights of the elements that appear on `:hover` in this demo are reported by the CSS and taken from the `data-heightwert` element as set by jQuery.

References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/).
- [`data-` custom arbitrary data-storage attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes).

Comment: thank you. You are right, thats class names. what i did now was to split that string into an array and use a for() to add that value to the attribute of every class item. i thank you for the data- example. this is really good!

Comment: is it possible to use the data-heightwert for coloring the element depending on the size in css?

Comment: Not in pure css, no; but you could use jQuery to assign a class-name based on the value and then assign colours to those classes.